# PhotoImage.zoom() error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently working on an application that reads intensities from .txt files and then converts the intensities to RGB before mapping them an image. Right now, I'm doing this by creating an empty tkinter.PhotoImage object and then filling the pixels with the RGB data. Up to this point it works fine, but when I try to use the PhotoImage.zoom() function to scale the image to fit my canvas, I get:

```
>>>resizedImage = image.zoom(30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
rIm = im.zoom(30)
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3249, in zoom
self.tk.call(destImage, 'copy', self.name, '-zoom',x,y)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "pyimage4"
```

The original image will draw just fine. The only time I get an error with it is when I try to zoom. I've looked through the documentation and the tkinter files and I can't find this error anywhere.

The function that creates the original image is the following:

```
def drawImage(filename, xPoints, yPoints, measurement, max, min):
xPosition = xPoints
yPosition = yPoints
im = PhotoImage(width = xPoints, height = yPoints)
for i in range(1, xPoints * yPoints + 1):

    tmp = linecache.getline(filename +'_raw_' + str(i) + '.txt', measurement)
    if eval(tmp[0:5]) < 100:
        wavelength = eval(tmp[0:5])
        intensity = eval(tmp[9:])
    elif eval(tmp[0:5]) >= 100 and eval(tmp[0:5]) < 1000:
        wavelength = eval(tmp[0:6])
        intensity = eval(tmp[10:])
    elif eval(tmp[0:5]) >= 1000:
        wavelength = eval(tmp[0:7])
        intensity = eval(tmp[11:])

    RGB = wav2RGB(wavadjust(intensity, max, min))

    im.put(RGB, (xPosition -1, yPosition - 1))
    xPosition -= 1
    if xPosition == 0:
        xPosition = xPoints
        yPosition -= 1
return im
```

wavadjust takes a measurement, along with the minimum and maximum measurements (read elsewhere) and spreads the measurements out to give a wider range of colors when converted to RGB. wav2RGB takes the adjusted measurement, converts it to RGB, and returns a tuple.

So the actual image creation is the following:

```
image = drawImage(filename, xPoints, yPoints, initMeasurement, max, min)
resizedImage = image.zoom(30)
```

Comment: It may help if you post some code that you suspect is responsible for this error.

Comment: I've edited the original to include the image creation code.

Comment: @Justin I have the same error as you. Did you find a way to solve it ?